# Problem when get id from data-url in django 2.2

Tags: python, django, django-forms, bootstrap-modal, django-2.2

this is my script:

views.py

```
from profil.models import dayah

def index(request):
dayah = profil_dayah.objects.all
return render(request,'index.html', { 'dayah' : dayah })
```

index.html

```
{% for dayahs in dayah %}
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary see-details" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalLong" data-url="{% url 'details' dayahs.id %}">Detail</button>
{% endfor %}
```

get_id.js

```
$(".see-details").on('click', function (){
  var url = $(this).data('url')
  console.log(url);
})
```

the result of console.log should be

```
/details/1
```

int 1 is the id from {{ dayahs.id }}
but my real result is :

```
/details/(%3FP4%5Cd/)
```

why the result like that? i want the result is /details/1 in the console.log

Comment: It looks like your url is invalid, likely you used `path`, but defined a regex-like syntax. Can you share your path definition?

Comment: Based on the path you show, you defined the path as something like `/details/(?P4\d)`, but without a parameter.

Comment: path('details/(?P<pk>\d/)', views.index, name='details'),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mixed [**`path(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urls/#path) syntax with [**`re_path(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urls/#re-path) syntax. The `path` syntax does not use regular expresssions, but path converters.

You thus should define your url as:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('details/<int:pk>/', views.index, name='details'),
    # …
]
```

Right now, Django takes your path literally, and thus construct a path that is percentage-encoded. If we percentage-decode it, we see:

```
/details/(?P4\d)
```

which thus does not really take into account the primary key.

Comment: its Work...  :)  (y) thank you very much @Willem Van Onsem, this really helped me. I am very grateful.

Comment: but when i will call the pk why the typeeror "index() missing 1 required positional argument: 'pk'"       def index(request, pk):  ID=pk   studys = get_object_or_404(study, name_dayah=ID)

Comment: @Mant: did you define your `def index` method with a `pk` parameter? It should be something like `def index(request, pk):`.

Comment: @Mant: did you by any change define another `path` with `views.index` as target function?

Comment: yes, i have2 path of `views.idex` this one `path('details/<int:pk>/)', views.index, name='details'),
    path('', views.index),`

Comment: @Mant: well the latter can not be a valid path, since your `index` view requires a `pk`, and it is not clear what the `pk` would be for the empty path.

Comment: so i have to make another `def` ? like `def details(request, pk)` ?

Comment: @Mant: I guess that is probably better yes.

Comment: I really want to thank you, but I am very ashamed because I have asked many questions. Once again, thank you @Willem. have a nice day :)